# Apply "grep -v" with patterns from multiple files to multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a lot of files like `1.txt`, `2.txt`, etc. and `1.search`, `2.search`, etc.

How can I use one `grep -v` on all of these, rather than write each time a command like this?

```
cat 1.txt | grep -f 1.search -v
```

and

```
cat 2.txt | grep -f 2.search -v
```

I tried

```
for i in 1..20 ; do
    grep -v -f /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/data/$i.search \
        /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/input/$i.txt > \
        /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/data/selection/$i.result.txt
done
```

but I get an error:

> ```
> grep: Unmatched [ or [^
> ```

Comment: No need for the `cat` here, just do `grep -f 1.search -v 1.txt`

Comment: Do the strings you search for differ?

Comment: `for i in 1 2 ; do grep -v -f $i.search $i.txt ; done`

Comment: I tried it for i in 1..20 ; do grep -v -f $i.search $i.txt ; done but I have an error grep: Unmatched [ or [^

Comment: I tried it for i in 1..20 ; do grep -v -f /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/data/$i.search /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/input/$i.txt > /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/data/selection/$i.result.txt ; done but I have an error grep: Unmatched [ or [^ – Dreem AT 6 mins ago

Comment: Please, do not add code in comments. Instead, [edit] your post.

Comment: The error indicates that the data in one of the `*.search` files is malformed.

Comment: how it is malformed ?

Comment: It has an "unmatched `[` or `[^`" just like the error message very specifically tells you.  An expression like `[foo` is not a valid regular expression; perhaps you mean `\[foo` or `grep -F` which changes the input pattern semantics -- with `-F` you just match `[foo` literally without attempting to interpret it as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-F` for a *fixed string* search:

```
for i in {1..20} ; do
    grep -vFf /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/data/$i.search \
        /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/input/$i.txt > \
        /home/DAT/Desktop/Project/data/selection/$i.result.txt
done
```

Otherwise `grep` treats characters from the input file which was specified via `-f` as *regular expressions*.